# SQL select another column with max during group by

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite database, and I am executing this query.

```
SELECT
  thread.id as id,
  thread.title as title,
  post.posted as posted,
  user.username as username
FROM post
INNER JOIN thread ON post.thread_id = thread.id
INNER JOIN user ON post.user_id = user.id
ORDER BY posted desc;
```

This gives me the following rows

```
5|Creating Thread|2017-07-23 08:05:15.730725|zrbecker
5|Creating Thread|2017-07-23 08:05:07.881327|zrbecker
4|This is a new thread|2017-07-23 05:14:08.513643|zrbecker
4|This is a new thread|2017-07-23 05:13:40.172866|admin
1|First Thread!|2017-07-23 05:10:43.772543|zrbecker
3|Here is a post|2017-07-23 04:58:10.999243|ralph
3|Here is a post|2017-07-23 04:52:49.060482|admin
3|Here is a post|2017-07-23 04:52:30.497092|admin
3|Here is a post|2017-07-23 04:50:53.800177|admin
2|Another Thread|2017-07-23 02:21:46.544810|ralph
1|First Thread!|2017-07-23 02:17:46.544810|ralph
1|First Thread!|2017-07-23 02:16:46.544810|admin
```

I want to do a "group by" where I group by thread.id, I want a last_posted, and first_posted column for the dates. But I also want last_username, and first_username to know the user that posted that post.

This was my first attempt.

```
SELECT
  thread.id as id,
  thread.title as title,
  count(post.id) as number_posts,
  max(post.posted) as last_posted,
  user.username as last_username,
  min(post.posted) as first_posted,
  user.username as first_username
FROM post
INNER JOIN thread ON post.thread_id = thread.id
INNER JOIN user ON post.user_id = user.id
GROUP BY thread_id
ORDER BY last_posted desc;
```

There isn't really a good reason I should expect that to work. It's seems like I need a max function that outputs both columns. Not just the column I am taking the max of.

Any help?

EDIT: Here is a .dump of my sqlite3 database

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE thread (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        title VARCHAR(80),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO thread VALUES(1,'First Thread!');
INSERT INTO thread VALUES(2,'Another Thread');
INSERT INTO thread VALUES(3,'Here is a post');
INSERT INTO thread VALUES(4,'This is a new thread');
INSERT INTO thread VALUES(5,'Creating Thread');
CREATE TABLE user (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        UNIQUE (username)
);
INSERT INTO user VALUES(1,'admin','test123');
INSERT INTO user VALUES(2,'ralph','password123');
INSERT INTO user VALUES(3,'zrbecker','helloworld');
CREATE TABLE post (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        user_id INTEGER,
        thread_id INTEGER,
        message TEXT NOT NULL,
        posted DATETIME,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user (id),
        FOREIGN KEY(thread_id) REFERENCES thread (id)
);
INSERT INTO post VALUES(1,1,1,'First Post!','2017-07-23 02:16:46.544810');
INSERT INTO post VALUES(2,2,1,'Second post!','2017-07-23 02:17:46.544810');
INSERT INTO post VALUES(3,2,2,'Another post','2017-07-23 02:21:46.544810');
INSERT INTO post VALUES(4,1,3,'Lorem Ipsum ','2017-07-23 04:50:53.800177');
INSERT INTO post VALUES(5,1,3,'test test','2017-07-23 04:52:30.497092');
INSERT INTO post VALUES(6,1,3,'test trest test','2017-07-23 04:52:49.060482');
INSERT INTO post VALUES(7,2,3,'Hello There','2017-07-23 04:58:10.999243');
INSERT INTO post VALUES(8,3,1,'hello','2017-07-23 05:10:43.772543');
INSERT INTO post VALUES(9,1,4,'This is my message','2017-07-23 05:13:40.172866');
INSERT INTO post VALUES(10,3,4,'hello','2017-07-23 05:14:08.513643');
INSERT INTO post VALUES(11,3,5,'This is a thread','2017-07-23 08:05:07.881327');
INSERT INTO post VALUES(12,3,5,'New post','2017-07-23 08:05:15.730725');
COMMIT;
```

I ended up coming up with a SQL query that seems to work. Seems quite complicated though. Hoping for something much simpler.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
  thread.id AS id,
  thread.title AS title,
  thread.post_count AS post_count,
  thread.last_posted AS last_posted,
  last_user.username AS last_username,
  thread.first_posted AS first_posted,
  first_user.username AS first_username
FROM (
  SELECT
    thread.id AS id,
    thread.title AS title,
    count(post.id) AS post_count,
    max(post.posted) AS last_posted,
    min(post.posted) AS first_posted
  FROM thread
  INNER JOIN post ON post.thread_id = thread.id
  GROUP BY thread.id
) AS thread
INNER JOIN post AS last_post
  ON last_post.thread_id = thread.id
  AND last_post.posted = thread.last_posted
INNER JOIN post AS first_post
  ON first_post.thread_id = thread.id
  AND first_post.posted = thread.first_posted
INNER JOIN user AS last_user ON last_post.user_id = last_user.id
INNER JOIN user AS first_user ON first_post.user_id = first_user.id
ORDER BY last_posted DESC;
```

Desired output looks like this:

```
5|Creating Thread|2|2017-07-23 08:05:15.730725|zrbecker|2017-07-23 08:05:07.881327|zrbecker
4|This is a new thread|2|2017-07-23 05:14:08.513643|zrbecker|2017-07-23 05:13:40.172866|admin
1|First Thread!|3|2017-07-23 05:10:43.772543|zrbecker|2017-07-23 02:16:46.544810|admin
3|Here is a post|4|2017-07-23 04:58:10.999243|ralph|2017-07-23 04:50:53.800177|admin
2|Another Thread|1|2017-07-23 02:21:46.544810|ralph|2017-07-23 02:21:46.544810|ralph
```

Another Edit: My ultimate goal is to craft a SQLAlchemy expression that will do this for me. When I couldn't figure out how to do it with the ORM, I decided to try to come up with a raw SQL query that could guide me. Any advice that would move me in that direction would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide `.dump` from SQLite commandline tool of a suitably tailored toy database as [mcve]. Include the desired output.

Comment: Added .dump and desired output. I ended up coming up with something that works. Although seems a bit crazy.

Comment: I guess one issue with my current query is that if I have two posts with date equal to the maximum, I'll probably get a thread with two rows.

Comment: Do not worry, you are not the first and will not be the last to find a solution while making a MCVE. I think it would be adequate now to change your question and focus it on the remaining problem (must be careful with changing questions, once you have an answer; that is not loved). Currently, the part with only wanting one (not two) for two occurences of maximum seems to be missing. Make sure that you either say "any of the occurrences" (i.e. you do not care) or "the occurrences with the maximum and the following additional condition..." (i.e. define how to choose).

Answer (score -1):

Try the query below

```
with postData as(
SELECT
post.*
,row_number() over (partition by  post.thread_id order by post.posted desc) descRowNumber
,row_number() over (partition by  post.thread_id order by post.posted ) ascRowNumber
FROM post
)
SELECT thread.id AS id,
thread.title AS title,
last_posted.posted AS last_postedDate,
last_user.username AS last_username,
first_posted.posted AS first_postedDate,
first_user.username AS first_username 
from
thread left join
  (select id,thread_id from postData where ascRowNumber=1) first_posted on first_posted.thread_id=thread.id
left join  
  (select id,thread_id from postData where descRowNumber=1) last_posted on last_posted.thread_id=thread.id
left JOIN [user] AS first_user ON first_posted.user_id = first_user.id
left JOIN [user] AS last_user ON last_posted.user_id = last_user.id
```